# Graphs in Jmeter

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I need to perform some load test via a jmeter and for this I have created a test plan that is going to be uploading files for some time while there also is a JDBC request selecting amount of not yet processed files.
Could anyone please help me with some advice how to put the resulting values from the JDBC listener into some meaningful graph?
In the graph I would like to have amount of unprocessed files on one axis and on the second one a time stamp from which the result is.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=your_variable_from_JDBC_request_with_number_of_files
```

This way when next time you [launch JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) you will see an extra column in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode) with the values for the number of not processed files for each and every Sample Result.

Going forward you can create a custom chart for the number of not processed files over time, see [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs) chapter for more details. You will need to change at least `jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_testGraph.property.set_Sample_Variable_Name` property value to match the one you set in the `sample_variables` and amend chart and axis titles according to your needs